# Filters not being preserved onRowAdd, onRowUpdate in material-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I am new to the material-table and wanted to know if there is a way by which we can save the filters in the table after onRowAdd or onRowDelete. I am using a functional-based class as follows:

```
import "./EditTable.css";
// import MaterialTable from 'material-table'
import MaterialTable from "@material-table/core";
import { Checkbox, Select, MenuItem, Container } from "@material-ui/core";
import axios from "axios";

function EditTable(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(props.techstacks);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState(true);
  const [year, setYear] = useState("all");
  const [newSoftwareID, setNewSoftwareID] = useState(0);
  const [openMultiEdit, setOpenMultiEdit] = useState(false);
  const [selectedToEdit, setSelectedToEdit] = useState([]);

  function set_new_software(props) {
    console.log(props.newValue.id);
  }

  const columns = [
    { title: "App/Component", field: "app_componenet_name" },
    {
      title: "Techstack Category",
      field: "techstack_category",
      lookup: {
        "Host OS": "Host OS",
        "Container OS": "Container OS",
        Mobile: "Mobile",
        Runtime: "Runtime",
        "App Containers": "App Containers",
        "Queues/Streaming": "Queues/Streaming",
        "Spring/Composition Lib": "Spring/Composition Lib",
        "Integration Lib": "Integration Lib",
        "Caching Lib": "Caching Lib",
        Databases: "Databases",
        "DB Driver": "DB Driver",
        "Security Lib": "Security Lib",
        "Log Aggregation": "Log Aggregation",
        Logging: "Logging",
        "Text Search/repo": "Text Search/repo",
        Presentation: "Presentation",
        Browser: "Browser",
        "Browser addons": "Browser addons",
        Misc: "Misc",
      },
    },
    {
      title: "Software Name",
      field: "techstack_software",

      customFilterAndSearch: (term, rowData) =>
        rowData.software_name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()),

      render: (rowData) => rowData.software_name,

      editComponent: (rowData) => (
        <SoftwareDropDown
          values={props.software_values}
          current_software={rowData.rowData.techstack_software_detail}
          callback={set_new_software}
          rowData={rowData}
          onChange={rowData.onChange}
        />
      ),
    },
    { title: "Container Source", field: "container_source" },
    {
      title: "Disposition",
      field: "techstack_software_detail.disposition",
      editable: "never",
    },
    { title: "Roadmap", field: "roadmap" },
    { title: "EA Comments", field: "EA_comments" },
    { title: "PA Comments", field: "PA_comments" },
  ];
  const handleChange = () => {
    setFilter(!filter);
  };

  const closeMultiEdit = (newValue) => {
    setOpenMultiEdit(newValue);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(props.techstacks);
  }, [props.techstacks]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container maxWidth="lg">
        <MaterialTable
          title="Techstack Data"
          data={data}
          columns={columns}
          editable={{
            onRowAdd: (newRow) =>
              new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                axios
                  .post(
                    `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/techstacks/`,
                    {
                      techstack_product: props.current_product,
                      app_componenet_name: newRow.app_componenet_name,
                      techstack_category: newRow.techstack_category,
                      techstack_software: newRow.techstack_software,
                      container_source: newRow.container_source,
                      roadmap: newRow.roadmap,
                      EA_comments: newRow.EA_comments,
                      PA_comments: newRow.PA_comments,
                    },
                    {
                      headers: { Accept: "application/json" },
                    }
                  )
                  .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    const updatedRows = [
                      ...data,
                      { id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100), ...newRow },
                    ];
                    setData(updatedRows);
                  })
                  .catch(function (error) {
                    alert(error);
                    reject(error);
                  })
                  .finally(function (response) {
                    props.getSoftwares();
                    resolve();
                  });
              }),
            onRowDelete: (selectedRow) =>
              new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                axios
                  .delete(
                    `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/techstacks/${selectedRow.id}/`,
                    {
                      headers: { Accept: "application/json" },
                    }
                  )
                  .then(function (response) {
                    const index = selectedRow.tableData.id;
                    const updatedRows = [...data];
                    updatedRows.splice(index, 1);
                    setData(updatedRows);
                  })
                  .catch(function (error) {
                    alert(error);
                    reject(error);
                  })
                  .finally(function (response) {
                    props.getSoftwares();
                    resolve();
                  });
              }),
            onRowUpdate: (updatedRow, oldRow) =>
              new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                axios
                  .patch(
                    `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/techstacks/${updatedRow.id}/`,
                    {
                      techstack_category: updatedRow.techstack_category,
                      app_componenet_name: updatedRow.app_componenet_name,
                      techstack_software: updatedRow.techstack_software,
                      container_source: updatedRow.container_source,
                      roadmap: updatedRow.roadmap,
                      EA_comments: updatedRow.EA_comments,
                      PA_comments: updatedRow.PA_comments,
                    },
                    {
                      headers: { Accept: "application/json" },
                    }
                  )
                  .then(function (response) {
                    const updatedRows = [...data];
                    const updateObjIndex = updatedRows.findIndex(
                      (x) => x.id === oldRow.tableData.id
                    );
                    if (updateObjIndex > -1) {
                      updatedRows[updateObjIndex] = updatedRow;
                      setData(updatedRows);
                    }
                  })
                  .catch(function (error) {
                    alert(error);
                    reject(error);
                  })
                  .finally(function (response) {
                    props.getSoftwares();
                    resolve();
                  });
              }),
          }}
          options={{
            filtering: filter,
            addRowPosition: "first",
            selection: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            pageSizeOptions: [5, 10, 25, 50, 100],
            paging: true,
            grouping: true,
          }}
          actions={[
            {
              tooltip: "Remove All Selected Items",
              icon: "delete",
              onClick: (evt, data) => {
                const to_delete = [];
                console.log(data[0].id);
                for (const item in data) {
                  to_delete.push(data[item].id);
                }
                alert(`You want to delete ${data.length} rows.`);

                const axiosArray = [];
                for (let x = 0; x < to_delete.length; x++) {
                  const newPromise = axios.delete(
                    `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/techstacks/${to_delete[x]}/`,
                    {
                      headers: { Accept: "application/json" },
                    }
                  );
                  axiosArray.push(newPromise);
                }

                axios
                  .all(axiosArray)
                  .then(
                    axios.spread((...responses) => {
                      responses.forEach((res) => console.log("Success"));
                      console.log("submitted all axios calls");
                    })
                  )
                  .catch((error) => {})
                  .finally(function (response) {
                    // Hide loading
                    props.getSoftwares();
                  });
              },
            },
          ]}
        />
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

export default EditTable;
```

When the user selects a filter, adds a row, or updates some record, the table re-renders and the filters are gone. Any help? Thanks